# Track across subdomains

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

What's the best way to track across subdomains? Here's the scenario:

Customers on my site can create their own custom site name or subdomain. For example, if John Doe signs up as a customer, they can create their own personal subdomain of: johndoe.mydomain.com. In a sense, subdomains are created dynamically as each new customer signs up and creates their own subdomain.

Once someone signs up as a customer, they have access, or the ability, to sign up for another service that allows them to accept online donations. Should they choose to buy this capability or product, they are taken to a subdomain of: admin.forms.com. It's on this subdomain where customers can purchase this add-on. So basically, customers are moving from their own custom subdomain to admin.forms.com to signup for this service.

The goal is to see how many customers are signing up for this service. Does it make sense to create a new property for admin.forms.com? Or should I use a view or segment?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/insight.

Answer (score 0):

Since the subdomains actually belong to different domains you would need to set up proper [cross-domain tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain) if you want to track across domain boundaries.

Pageviews by the same visitor are connected to a session via the clientId. The clientId is stored in a cookie. Cookies are domain specific. Since cookies from mydomain.com cannot be read by a client browsing forms.com the clientId needs to be carried over as query string parameter. That's what cross domain tracking does.

Since you want to view traffic to your two (sub)domains as if this was a single domain (i.e. you want an uninterrupted "user journey") using additional views or properties would defy your purpose).

Unless you specifically set the cookieDomain value either to "auto" or to the top domain the cookie will be valid for the subdomain(s) only, so you won't have to worry that this interferes with tracking on the top domain level (however if you expect users to browser on the top domain level (e.g. switch from admin.forms.com to plain forms.com) then you should set the cookieDomain field to auto, else GA will allocate a new clientId when the user switches from subdomain to main domain).

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I greatly appreciate it.